# How to unwrap optional value returns nil although it has value?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this piece of code where i am unwrapping an optional value, and in the debugger there is a value in this optional variable. But for some reason it is giving me null pointer exception !!!

[image: Code]

[image: Debugger]

[image]

Can any one explain why its finding nil although there is a value !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like self.fullresolutionimages, the array/dictionary, is the nil that is causing the error.

make sure that you allocate that first, `self.fullResolutionImages = [UIImage]()`;

Also, I am not 100% sure if doing the index when there are no contents will work, so you may want to append instead, `self.fullResolutionImages.append(self.fullResolutionImage)`, or insert this way, `self.fullResolutionImages.insert(self.fullResolutionImage, atIndex: 0)`

Answer (score 0):

fullResolutionImages = nil, the message is correct, isn't it?